# ng-class not working inside directive template

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-class

I'm trying to set a CSS class to a button inside a **directive's template** through **ng-class** but it's not working. Is there anything wrong with the code?

```
.directive('aButtons', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        replace:true,
        template:
            '<div class="panel-footer">' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn double left-btn btn-danger remove" ng-click="remove()" ng-show="canRemove()">Remove</button>'+
                '<button type="button" class="btn right-btn btn-warning revert" ng-class="{\'double\':canRemove()}" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>'+
            '</div>'                
        }
    };
})
```

the idea is to set the button width to 50% when the first one is visible. (the default width is 100%).

Comment: Can you post the code where `remove` and `canRemove` are defined? And are you sure they are available to the scope of this directive. If you output {{canRemove()}} somewhere does it change when your button is clicked?

Comment: you'd better show us how and where `canRemove()` is defined.

Comment: The canRemove() effectively works in the ng-show and also with the ng-click ... I think it's a specific problem about the ng-class inside the template.

Comment: How exactly is it not working? Also what is the CSS for the .double class?